# How do I make a space be accepted in the input

Tags: java

So I made a Blackjack game and it work fine but I found this error when I was testing. If someone input their name with a space the game breaks and errors. So how can I fix that. **I have tried next() abd nextLine() didn't work.** Down below is my code the Blood part is where the fix should happen. But I am not sure how to fix it.

**The Game:**

BLACKJACK RULES:
-Each player is dealt 2 cards. The dealer is dealt 2 cards with one face-up and one face-down.
-Cards are equal to their value with face cards being 10 and an Ace being 1 or 11.
-The players cards are added up for their total.
-Players Hit to gain another card from the deck. Players Stay to keep their current card total.
-Dealer Hits until they equal or exceed 17.
-The goal is to have a higher card total than the dealer without going over 21.
-If the player total equals the dealer total, it is a Push and the hand ends.
-Players win their bet if they beat the dealer. Players win 1.5x their bet if they get Blackjack which is 21.
-Note that: (C) Clubs (?), (D) Diamonds (?), (H) Hearts (?), (S) Spades (?), (J) Jack (?,?,?,?), (Q) Queen (?,?,?,?) and (K) King (?,?,?,?).

How many people are playing (1-6)? 1
What is player 1's name? **sa mi**   <<< this where it crashes
How much do you want to bet sa, you got (1-100) J Coins?

**My Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackjackGame {

    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int users;
    private Player[] players;
    private Deck deck;
    private Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

    // Starts game and displays the rules
    public void initializeGame() {
        String names;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("  BLACKJACK RULES: ");
        System.out.println(
                "    -Each player is dealt 2 cards. The dealer is dealt 2 cards with one face-up and one face-down.");
        System.out.println("    -Cards are equal to their value with face cards being 10 and an Ace being 1 or 11.");
        System.out.println("    -The players cards are added up for their total.");
        System.out.println(
                "    -Players Hit to gain another card from the deck. Players Stay to keep their current card total.");
        System.out.println("    -Dealer Hits until they equal or exceed 17.");
        System.out.println("    -The goal is to have a higher card total than the dealer without going over 21.");
        System.out.println("    -If the player total equals the dealer total, it is a Push and the hand ends.");
        System.out.println(
                "    -Players win their bet if they beat the dealer. Players win 1.5x their bet if they get Blackjack which is 21.");
        System.out.println(
                "        -Note that: (C) Clubs (♣), (D) Diamonds (♦), (H) Hearts (♥), (S) Spades (♠), (J) Jack (♣,♦,♥,♠), (Q) Queen (♣,♦,♥,♠) and (K) King (♣,♦,♥,♠).");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        // Gets the amount of players and creates them. Check that only up to 6 players
        // can play.
        do {
            System.out.print("How many people are playing (1-6)? "); // The Game can be played with 1-6 player.
            users = input.nextInt();
            if (users >= 7) { // there can only be 6 players anything higher re-ask how many player.
                System.out.println("Invalid entry. There can't be this much player's. Up to 1-6 player only.");
            }

        } while (users > 6 || users < 0);

        players = new Player[users];
        deck = new Deck();

       ** // Asks for player names and assigns them
        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            System.out.print("What is player " + (i + 1) + "'s name? ");
            names = input.next();
            players[i] = new Player();
            players[i].setName(names);
        }**
    }

    // Shuffles the deck
    public void shuffle() throws InvalidDeckPositionException, InvalidCardSuitException, InvalidCardValueException,
            InvalidSpaceException {
        deck.shuffle();

    }

    // Gets the bets from the players
    public void getBets() {
        int betValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBank() > 0) {
                do {
                    System.out.print("How much do you want to bet " + players[i].getName() + ", you got"
                            + (" (1-" + players[i].getBank()) + ") " + "J Coins? ");
                    betValue = input.nextInt();
                    players[i].setBet(betValue);
                } while (!(betValue > 0 && betValue <= players[i].getBank()));
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }

    }

    // Deals the cards to the players and dealer
    public void dealCards() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
                if (players[i].getBank() > 0) {
                    players[i].addCard(deck.nextCard());
                }
            }

            dealer.addCard(deck.nextCard());
        }
    }

    // Initial check for dealer or player Blackjack
    public void checkBlackjack() {
        // System.out.println();

        if (dealer.isBlackjack()) {
            System.out.println("Dealer has BlackJack!");
            for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
                if (players[i].getTotal() == 21) {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " pushes");
                    players[i].push();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " loses");
                    players[i].bust();
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (dealer.peek()) {
                System.out.println("Dealer peeks and does not have a BlackJack");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
                if (players[i].getTotal() == 21) {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has blackjack!");
                    players[i].blackjack();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This code takes the user commands to hit or stand
    public void hitOrStand() {
        String command;
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBet() > 0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has " + players[i].getHandString());

                do {
                    do {
                        System.out.print(players[i].getName() + " (H)it or (S)tand? ");
                        command = input.next();
                        c = command.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                    } while (!(c == 'H' || c == 'S'));
                    if (c == 'H') {
                        players[i].addCard(deck.nextCard());
                        System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has " + players[i].getHandString());
                    }
                } while (c != 'S' && players[i].getTotal() <= 21);
            }
        }
    }

    // Code for the dealer to play
    public void dealerPlays() {
        boolean isSomePlayerStillInTheGame = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < users && isSomePlayerStillInTheGame == false; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBet() > 0 && players[i].getTotal() <= 21) {
                isSomePlayerStillInTheGame = true;
            }
        }
        if (isSomePlayerStillInTheGame) {
            dealer.dealerPlay(deck);
        }
    }

    // This code calculates all possible outcomes and adds or removes the player
    // bets
    public void settleBets() {
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBet() > 0) {
                if (players[i].getTotal() > 21) {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has busted");
                    players[i].bust();
                } else if (players[i].getTotal() == dealer.calculateTotal()) {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has pushed");
                    players[i].push();
                } else if (players[i].getTotal() < dealer.calculateTotal() && dealer.calculateTotal() <= 21) {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has lost");
                    players[i].loss();
                } else if (players[i].getTotal() == 21) {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has won with blackjack!");
                    players[i].blackjack();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has won");
                    players[i].win();

                }
            }
        }

    }

    // This prints the players hands
    public void printStatus() {
        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBank() > 0) {
                System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has " + players[i].getHandString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Dealer has " + dealer.getHandString(true, true));
    }

    // This prints the players banks and tells the player if s/he is out of the game
    public void printMoney() {
        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBank() > 0) {
                System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has " + players[i].getBank() + " J Coins ");
            }
            if (players[i].getBank() == 0) {
                System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has " + players[i].getBank() + " J Coins "
                        + " and is out of the game.");
                players[i].removeFromGame();
            }
        }
    }

    // This code resets all hands
    public void clearHands() {
        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            players[i].clearHand();
        }
        dealer.clearHand();

    }

    // This decides to force the game to end when all players lose or lets players
    // choose to keep playing or not
    public boolean playAgain() {
        String command;
        char c;
        Boolean playState = true;
        if (forceEnd()) {
            playState = false;
        } else {
            do {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Do you want to play again (Y)es or (N)o? ");
                command = input.next();
                c = command.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            } while (!(c == 'Y' || c == 'N'));
            if (c == 'N') {
                playState = false;
            }
        }
        return playState;
    }

    // This says true or false to forcing the game to end
    public boolean forceEnd() {
        boolean end = false;
        int endCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBank() == -1) {
                endCount++;
            }
        }
        if (endCount == users) {
            end = true;
        }
        if (end) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("All players have lost and the game ends.");
        }

        return end;
    }

    // This is the endgame code for when all players are out of the game or players
    // decide to stop playing
    public void endGame() {
        int endAmount;
        String endState = " no change.";
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) {
            if (players[i].getBank() == -1) {
                players[i].resetBank();
            }
            endAmount = players[i].getBank() - 100;
            if (endAmount > 0) {
                endState = " gain of ";
            } else if (endAmount < 0) {
                endState = " loss of ";
            }
            System.out.println(players[i].getName() + " has ended the game with " + players[i].getBank() + ".");
            if (endState != " no change.") {
                System.out.println("A" + endState + Math.abs(endAmount) + ".");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No change from their starting value.");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
    }

} // End class
```

**I have tried next() abd nextLine() didn't work.**

Doing nextLine() broke the code even more when I run it and play the game.